# SEF (Search Engine Friedly URLs) in express.js site

Tags: heroku, express, search-engine

I use express.js for my site which is hosted on Heroku. My pages are not SEF now and look like http://domain.com/person/1. I want to add synonims (redirect?) for such links like http://domain.com/person/alex. Are there any solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Change your current route `/person/:id` which does some kind of `Person.fetchById(req.params.id)`

to `/person/:nickname` which will do a `Person.fetchByNickname(req.params.nickname)`

You'll need to have those nicknames in your database (you can concat a firstName and a lastName for example, but you have **to make sure this key will be unique** - I suggest you make an index).

*Note: If you want to keep both routes working together on `/person`, you might want to you use regexp in your routes (to match number versus string)*

Comment: You could also do `/person/:id/:nickname`, fetch on ID and 301 redirect if req.params.nickname doesn't match the retrieved record.

Comment: Looks like I provided a bad example with `person` route. Imagine that I have `news` route instead. So I have route /news/:id and I need a SEF route /news/:the-sef-news-name. This news name is